# How to tell if Airplay streaming failed?

Tags: ios, airplay, tvos, apple-tv

I'm working on a video content app that features both live stream and a VOD with ads. For DRM reasons we need to use different streams when playing the VOD on the device / streaming over AirPlay. When I do that switch and try to start streaming to AirPlay with a new AVPlayer , every so often the Apple TV will display this message:

> An error occurred loading this content.

I'm observing the AVPlayer status through KVO, but it doesn't seem to change the status to 'AVPlayerStatusFailed' when this happens, so I don't know when close the video playback or start a retry logic.

Do we get any notification for this?